# What is the operating principle of IOS Unit Testing Bundle in Xcode 10?

Tags: unit-testing, xctest

please ask the operating principle of IOS Unit Testing Bundle in Xcode 10, such as how the unit test Bundle is compiled? How does the test cases execute? What is the relationship with the tested APP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing a book that describes this. Basically, when you run tests against an iOS app:

1. Xcode builds the test bundle. Since the tests are dependent on the app, it first builds the app.
2. It launches the app.
3. It injects the test bundle into the running app.
4. It tells the test runner to start.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be better if you could be more detailed. There is too little information about it on the Internet.

Comment: I don't have much more information about the mechanics I listed. But what other questions do you have?